# openstack: how to run multiple glance instances?

Tags: openstack

I'm new to openstack. And I have followed the installation guide to set an openstack on a single host server. Now I got a question. On the single node, I registered a glance service and relative endpoints in keystone. If I want to run glance on multiple host servers, do I need to register two glance services in keystone? Or do I still just need one glance service but add more glance endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to run multiple glance instances.  Then setup your keystone service catalog to point to a load balancer that will balance traffic between the many glance api endpoints.

currently there is no built in way to handle this.

There is some useful HA stuff discussed here:

http://www.hastexo.com/resources/presentations/high-availability-openstack